# How to concatenate an object and an array without mutating?

Tags: javascript, arrays

I'm trying to add an object at the beginning of an array without changing the original array (without mutating). I succeed appending it at the end with concat method, but unable to change the order. Any ideas?

```
const addOnData = {
  id: 0,
  value: "ID 0"
}

const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "ID 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "ID 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "ID 3"
  },
]

btn[1].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  const newArray = addOnData.concat(array);
  console.log(newArray);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Comment: `[addOnData, ...array]`

Comment: you never use the new array ...

Comment: @jabaa perfect, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

`addOnData` is an object, not an array, so you have to do either

```
const newArray = [addOnData].concat(array);
```

or

```
const newArray = [addOnData, ...array];
```

```js
const addOnData = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra data"
}

const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Value for ID 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Value for ID 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Value for ID 3"
  },
]

console.log([addOnData].concat(array))
console.log([addOnData,...array])
```

Answer (score 0):

You can create a new array with the new element and all elements from `array`

```
const addOnData = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra data"
}

const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Value for ID 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Value for ID 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Value for ID 3"
  },
]

btn[1].addEventListener('click', (e)=>{
  const newArray = [addOnData, ...array];
  console.log(newArray);
  e.stopPropagation();
});
```

Example

```js
const addOnData = {
  id: 10,
  value: "Extra data"
}

const array = [
  {
    id: 1,
    value: "Value for ID 1"
  },
  {
    id: 2,
    value: "Value for ID 2"
  },
  {
    id: 3,
    value: "Value for ID 3"
  },
]

const newArray = [addOnData, ...array];
console.log(newArray);
```